# Finding unique value of $x$ for the equation $x=\log_3(17-x^3)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, systems-of-equations

I was able to find the common point of intersection by plotting the graph of $x$ and $\log_3(17-x^3)$ which is $x=2$. But how can it be concluded without using graphs if the equation is $x=\log_3(17-x^3)$.

Comment: By guessing? ${}$

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to know whether or not the equality has a solution, without knowing that 2 is the solution.

If the functions on both sides of the equality are continuous (which is the case in the example), you can use the intermediate value theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) to conclude that the equation has a solution. For example, the function $x-\log_3(17-x^3)$ takes a negative value for $x=1.9$ and a positive value for $x=2.1$, therefore it must take the value zero somewhere in between. The key point is that it may be much easier to find two points where the function is positive and negative than it is to find a point where the function is zero.

Comment: Can modular arithmetic help after making an assumption that x is an integer ?

Comment: That's an excellent question, but I'm not sure if, and how exactly, it would help.

Comment: Still thanks a lot for the help,means a lot.

Comment: You're most welcome. Good luck in your mathematical adventures!

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of equation where you have to be lucky and guess an answer. If the solution is nice, that means $17-x^3$ is a power of $3$. That basically only leaves $x=2$ as a possibility. We check and verify that that is indeed a solution.

The equations $x=\log_3(16-x^3)$ or $x=\log_3(18-x^3)$ are unsolvable with regular high school algebra. We can prove that a solution exists, but not find it.